# how to solve this differential equation $(3(x^5)+3(x^2)(y^2))dx + (2(y^3)-2(x^3)y)dy = 0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

This is my first question here. 
I tried to solve this ODE.

[image]

This is the Wolfram's answer but there's a step-by-step solution.
:(

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$$(x^3+y^2)3x^2dx+(y^2-x^3)2ydy=0$$
HINT :

Obviously, this form suggests the change of variables : $\begin{cases} x^3=X \\ y^2=Y \end{cases}$
$$(X+Y)dX+(Y-X)dY=0$$
I suppose that you can take it from here.

HINT : change of function $Y=XF(X)\quad\to$ first order linear ODE.

Comment: Thanks, I'll práctica more :)